Enable a table row-specific class background to overwrite a cell-specific class background in a striped table
While building a striped Bootstrap table using Bootstrap v5.3.3, I need to be able to display some cells with a red background using the Bootstrap "table-danger" class. I also need to be able to highlight an entire row using the "table-warning" class. However I am unable to produce the expected results.
In the example below, all the cells of the last column have the "table-danger" class. Using CSS, I expect all the td elements that have the "table-danger" class inside a tr with the "table-warning" class to have the #fff3cd background-color.
In theory, rows #1 and #2 should display the expected behavior. In practice however, only row #2 display the expected behavior. The #1 row's background is still red, while it should be yellow. If I inspect the "New-York" cell, the background color value is as expected, but it does not display that value.
I do not understand what is causing this behavior.


    /* Higher specificity to target the table-danger cells inside table-warning rows */
    tr.table-warning td.table-danger {
        background-color: #fff3cd !important;
        /* Ensure the table-warning background color is applied */
    }
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-warning">
                    <th scope="col">Row</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Age</th>
                    <th scope="col">City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-warning">
                    <td>#1</td>
                    <td>John Doe</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td class="table-danger">New York</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-warning">
                    <td>#2</td>
                    <td>Jane Smith</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td class="table-danger">London</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#3</td>
                    <td>Mark Johnson</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td class="table-danger">Paris</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>




The problem is that the cells with table-danger class are in a tr with a table-warning class. A cell can't have two backgrounds colors. So you have to make a choice.
Here is code who solve your problem :


.last-cell {
        background-color: #fff3cd !important;
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      <div class="container mt-5">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr class="table-warning">
              <th scope="col">Row</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Age</th>
              <th scope="col">City</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="table-warning">
              <td>#1</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td class="last-cell">New York</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table-warning">
              <td>#2</td>
              <td>Jane Smith</td>
              <td>30</td>
              <td class="last-cell">London</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>#3</td>
              <td>Mark Johnson</td>
              <td>35</td>
              <td class="">Paris</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>



Hope it helps!
